# Using real time tooltip in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Many developer can write real time tooltip for him self.
So, if you don't understanding my question, here is example

[image: Not real time]

I want the tooltip following my cursor with smooth, can anybody tell me the code?

Comment: What do you mean?, please be specific

Comment: Like [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tooltip)?

Comment: Simply display the `ToolTip` yourself in code rather than relying on the system to display it automatically.

Comment: @JacobSeleznev No, i want to more than that, i am do that in easy way

Comment: @jmcilhinney No like that

Comment: @Danny I want to the tooltip following my cursor

Comment: @FunnyMan That not make it sense? Maybe i can help you

Comment: Yes like that. If you're not going to use your brain then what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you asked for.  As I said, you simply have to show the `ToolTip` yourself and not rely on the system to do it for you.

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseMove
    Dim text = e.Location.ToString()

    If text <> Me.ToolTip1.GetToolTip(Me.Button1) Then
        Me.ToolTip1.Show(e.Location.ToString(), Me.Button1, New Point(e.X + 20, e.Y + 20))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave
    Me.ToolTip1.Hide(Me.Button1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, your code not simply, i want just 1 line of code :-)

Comment: Because i thinking if have many lines in my app, my app will slow to load

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you're going to have to have a very large number of extra lines of code for it to make any noticeable difference to the loading time of your application. There will absolutely no measurable difference in the loading time of your app whether you have a one-line solution or use my code. It will make exactly zero difference. Execution time is a different matter but then fewer lines of code make take longer to execute if they do more work.

Comment: You dont know how to show a tooltip where ever you'd like, but you can judge that 3 lines of code is too much???  Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tooltip to follow the mouse, maybe use a timer and something like [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?710227-Show-a-tooltip-under-the-mouse-cursor)

```
Public Class Form1

Private toolTipMsg As String = "Busy, Please Wait..." & vbCrLf & "Line2 Blah bla bla."

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ToolTip1.Active = True
    ToolTip1.IsBalloon = False
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ' get cursor position
    Dim cp = Cursor.Position
    ' offset Y so tooltip is under mouse
    cp.Y += CInt(Cursor.Size.Height * 1.5)
    ' show tooltip
    ToolTip1.Show(toolTipMsg, Me, PointToClient(cp))
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code always showing the tooltip with the text "Busy, Please Wait...Line2 Blah bla bla."

Comment: You can change the message to anything `toolTipMsg = ..`